# Dijkstra's algorithm in Graphs.jl package of Julia

Tags: julia, shortest-path

From the [documentation](http://graphsjl-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/algorithms.html#shortest-paths) of `Graphs.jl`:

Dijkstra’s Algorithm

```
dijkstra_shortest_paths(graph, edge_dists, source[, visitor])

Performs Dijkstra’s algorithm to find shortest paths to all vertices from input sources.

Parameters: 
graph – The input graph
edge_dists – The vector of edge distances or an edge property inspector.
source – The source vertex (or vertices)
visitor – An visitor instance

Returns:    
An instance of DijkstraStates that encapsulates the results.
```

It says `source` is the source vertex, or vertices. Does it mean that this function can deal with multiple origins?

I am interested in finding shortest paths from multiple origins to multiple destinations. Can I do it using this function? Then, what the structure of `parents` array from the result will be?

Comment: Good you've read the docs.  Have a look at the `Graphs.jl` package [Dijkstra tests](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Graphs.jl/blob/master/test/dijkstra.jl) and see if that helps.

Comment: @rickhg12hs Thanks. But the test code doesn't include a case for multiple origins.

Comment: Using the example from the [docs](http://graphsjl-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/algorithms.html#shortest-paths),  have a look at `parents` and `dists` of `r = dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, dists, 1)`, `r = dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, dists, [1, 2])`, `r = dijkstra_shortest_paths(g, dists, [1, 2, 3])`, etc.